# Error installing simplejson using easy_install

Tags: python, easy-install, simplejson

When I try to install `simplejson` for python using easy_install I get the following error.

```
Searching for simplejson
Reading http://cheeseshop.python.org/pypi/simplejson/
Reading http://github.com/simplejson/simplejson
Reading http://cheeseshop.python.org/pypi/simplejson/3.3.0
Best match: simplejson 3.3.0
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/simplejson/simplejson-3.3.0.tar.gz
Processing simplejson-3.3.0.tar.gz
Running simplejson-3.3.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-myQdjt/simplejson-3.3.0/egg-dist-tmp-fSRixt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install", line 7, in ?
    sys.exit(
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1670, in main
    with_ei_usage(lambda:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1659, in with_ei_usage
    return f()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1674, in <lambda>
    distclass=DistributionWithoutHelpCommands, **kw
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/distutils/core.py", line 149, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/distutils/dist.py", line 946, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 211, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 446, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 471, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 655, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 930, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 919, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 26, in run_setup
    DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 63, in run
    return func()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 29, in <lambda>
    {'__file__':setup_script, '__name__':'__main__'}
  File "setup.py", line 14
    with open('README.rst', 'r') as f:
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Output for `cat /proc/version`

```
Linux version 2.6.18-164.el5 (mockbuild@x86-003.build.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)) #1 SMP Tue Aug 18 15:51:48 EDT 2009
```

Any comments on what can be the issue. I think I did pretty standard installation.

Answer (score 1):

Your Python version (2.4) is too old for the most recent simplejson version since it uses the "with" statement with is not available in Python 2.4. Upgrade your Python version or try an older version of simplejson or switch to a Python 2.4 compatible json module if you can not upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
get http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/simplejson/simplejson-2.0.9.tar.gz#md5=af5e67a39ca3408563411d357e6d5e47
tar xzvf simplejson-2.0.9.tar.gz
cd simplejson-2.0.9
sudo python setup.py install
```